# Logical and between directories in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, directory, directory-structure

I'm updating an old shell script to run with a new configuration and I'm relatively new to shell scripting, but I've been generally alright for most of the script. However, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what the following line is doing. This particular line is being called from another running script and is being run on UNIX type machines, though I'm not sure how relevant that is.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

My question is basically, what directory is this actually pointing to relative to the directory it is called in and stored in? Also what exactly is that && doing there? It seems very odd to see a logical operator beween two directories, but again I'm fairly new to shell scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just saves the dir the script is located in:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

The `commandA && commandB` condition is evaluated like this:

`commandB` is  executed if, and only if, `commandA` returns an exit status of zero. Being `cd something`, it will return true if the dir `something` exists. If not, it will return an exit status false so `pwd` will not be executed.

Graphically, it can be explained as:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &&        pwd          )"
DIR="$( cd (    dir (  name_of_script  )   )  &&  print current dir  )"
DIR="$( move to the dir of the script         &&  print current dir  )"
DIR= "name of the dir you have moved , that is, the dir of the script"
```

Comment: Oh woah. I never even thought of short circuiting working like that. That's awesome!

Comment: Well nearly: if the dir exists, it moves to it. Otherwise it gets empty data. I hope it is clear with my edit.

Comment: +1, but I want to address "executed if the first part is true": as [the manual says](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) of "command1 && command2": "command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status of zero." So, it's not exactly about true or false, it's about success or failure. The cd command can fail (if the specified directory does not exist), in which case, don't print the current working directory.

Comment: Based on your comment I updated my answer to try to make it more clear. Further suggestions will be welcome, sometimes my explanations are not as clear as I would like to :) Thank you, @glennjackman!

Answer (score 2):

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
|     |  |  |   |          |___ First value   |   |______ prints current working directory
|     |  |  |   |               of array      |___Logical AND operator
|     |  |  |   |__ Command to strip non-directory suffix
|     |  |  |
|     |  |  |__ Doing command substitution again to evaluate whats inside $()
|     |  |
|     |  |___ Changing directory
|     |
|     |_____ $() is construct for command substitution
|
|____ Creating and assigning a variable called DIR
```

Comment: +1 I like your way of representing info more than mine. We are such ASCII artists :)

Comment: Also appreciate the ASCII art, but I ultimately found the breakdown of the function to help more in my understanding of how the function was working, so despite how cool this is I'm going to have to go with fedorqui.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus No problem, best answer should be helpful not beautiful!! :)

Comment: Note that I +1 also because of the quality of the answer, not only the ASCII. Maybe this way it looses the progressive steps that the code does. Anyway, good job!

Comment: Aah @fedorqui you are far too kind sir! :)